# 品詞を指定して形態素解析

Tags: python, 自然言語処理

`readtextlist`を名詞・動詞・形容詞に絞って形態素解析したいのですが、 すべての品詞がアウトプットされてしまいます。

```
import MeCab

words_list = []

t = MeCab.Tagger('-d /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mecab/dic/mecab-ipadic-neologd')
for s in readtextlist:
   s_parsed = t.parse(s[0])
   words_s = []
   for line in s_parsed.splitlines()[:-1]:
      word = line.split("\t")[0]
      if word == 'EOS':
         break
      else:
         pos = line.split('\t')[1]
         slice = pos.split(',')
         if (slice[0] in ['名詞','動詞','形容詞']):
            words_s.append(slice[6])
         else:
            words_s.append(word)
   words_list.append(words_s)

print(words_list)
```

Comment: `s_parsed = t.parse(s[0])` の `s[0]` という箇所が少し気に掛かるのですが、`readtextlist` の中身を数個程度でよいので追記してもらえませんか？

Comment: Instagramの投稿文になります。['@@@投稿文@@@  #ykunieda  #cake #special #Premium #Apple #boulangerie #patisserie #applepie #パン #ケーキ #クロワッサン #タルト'],
 ['@@@投稿文@@@#パン#ぱん#お家ぱん#お家パン#手作りぱん#手作りパン#チーズとごま#チーズパン#パン好き#パン活'],・・・

Comment: `if (slice[0] in ['名詞','動詞','形容詞']): words_s.append(slice[6]) else: words_s.append(word)` の部分で 名詞, 動詞, 形容詞以外のワードも全て `words_s` に追加してしまっていますが、この部分は不要ではないでしょうか。

Comment: 'else:words_s.append(word)' を削除したところ、アウトプットが空になってしまいました。

Comment: こちらで試してみた所、`[['投稿', '文', 'ykunieda', 'cake', 'special', 'Premium', ...` と表示されますね……

Comment: すみません、提示したテキストが名詞ばかりでしたね・・・次のテキストだといかがでしょうか・・['私はパン屋でパンを買います #ykunieda #cake #special #Premium #Apple #boulangerie #patisserie #applepie #パン #ケーキ #クロワッサン #タルト'], ['私は自分でパンを焼きます#パン#ぱん#お家ぱん#お家パン#手作りぱん#手作りパン#チーズとごま#チーズパン#パン好き#パン活']

Comment: `'-d /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mecab/dic/mecab-ipadic-neologd'`　を削除してみても、うまくいきませんでした。`if (slice[0] in ['名詞','動詞','形容詞']):　`で品詞を正しく識別できていない、ということなのでしょうか・・・？

Comment: 結果は `[['私', 'パン屋', 'パン', '買い',  ...` になりました。辞書(neolog-d)の文字コードは UTF-8 ですね？

Comment: すみません、neolog-dの文字コードの確認の方法がわかりません。ひとまずneolog-dを使わずにMeCabのみで形態素解析でも問題無いのですが、やはり`if (slice[0] in ['名詞','動詞','形容詞']):`　部分で品詞の識別ができていないのでしょうか・・

Comment: はい、そうなります。ただ、else 節を付けた状態で表示される結果が文字化けしていないとすれば辞書に問題はないのかもしれません。

Comment: else節を付けた状態で表示される結果では、文字化けしていません。`[['私', ’は’,'パン屋','で', 'パン','を', '買い','ます','。' ...` といったように表示されます。

Comment: 参考までに、こちらの環境は Ubuntu 19.10/python 3.7.5/python-mecab 0.996 で、mecab-ipadic-neologd は https://github.com/neologd/mecab-ipadic-neologd/ をインストールしています。

Comment: それと、`s_parsed = t.parse(s[0])` の直後に `print(s_parsed)` を追加してパースの状況を確認してみると何か分かるかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。`print(s_parsed)`を実行したところ形態素解析自体は成功しているようです。

Comment: 原因がはっきりしないのですがsliceがうまくいっていなかったようで、以下で解決できました。ありがとうございました。
`words_list = []

t = MeCab.Tagger('-d /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mecab/dic/mecab-ipadic-neologd')
for s in readtextlist:
   s_parsed = t.parse(s[0])
   words_s = []
   for line in s_parsed.splitlines()[:-1]:
      word = line.split("\t")[0]
      if word == 'EOS':
         break
      else:
         pos = line.split('\t')[-1]
         slice = pos.split(',')
         if (slice[0] in ['名詞','動詞','形容詞']):
            words_s.append(word)

   words_list.append(words_s)

print(words_list)`

Answer (score 0):

原因がはっきりしないのですがsliceがうまくいっていなかったようで、以下で解決できました。
ありがとうございました。

```
words_list = []

t = MeCab.Tagger('-d /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mecab/dic/mecab-ipadic-neologd') 
for s in readtextlist: 
    s_parsed = t.parse(s[0]) 
    words_s = []
    for line in s_parsed.splitlines()[:-1]: 
        word = line.split("\t")[0] 
        if word == 'EOS': 
            break
        else: 
            pos = line.split('\t')[-1] 
            slice = pos.split(',') 
            if (slice[0] in ['名詞','動詞','形容詞']): 
                words_s.append(word) 
    words_list.append(words_s)

print(words_list)
```